# write a query to identify discrepancy

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with Student ID's and Student Names. There has been issues with assigning unique Student Id's to students and Hence I want to find the duplicates

Here is the sample Table:

```
Student ID  Student Name
   1                 Jack
   1                 John
   1                 Bill
   2                 Amanda
   2                 Molly
   3                 Ron
   4                 Matt
   5                 James
   6                 Kathy
   6                 Will
```

Here I want a third column "Duplicate_Count" to display count of duplicate records. 
For e.g. "Duplicate_Count" would display "3" for Student ID = 1 and so on. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you've sorted them out put a unique restraint or primary key on if you can, assuming you don't want to reuse them at a later date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Select StudentId, Count(*) DupCount
  From Table
  Group By StudentId
  Having Count(*) > 1
  Order By Count(*) desc,
```

Comment: I get the following error: 
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Count(*) DupCount'

Comment: Access requires AS when you assign an alias to a field expression, so `Count(*) AS DupCount`  However it will allow you to alias a data source in the FROM clause without using AS.  Inconsistent and confusing!

Comment: Should that be `(COUNT(*) - 1) AS DupCount` --i.e. if two values are the same only one is the duplicate? ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
  aa.StudentId, aa.StudentName, bb.DupCount
from
  Table as aa
join
(
  Select StudentId, Count(*) as DupCount from Table group by StudentId
) as bb
on aa.StudentId = bb.StudentId
```

The virtual table gives the count for each StudentId, this is joined back to the original table to add the count to each student record.

If you want to add a column to the table to hold dupcount, this query can be used in an update statement to update that column in the table

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
update mytable
set duplicate_count = (select count(*) from mytable t where t.id = mytable.id)
```

UPDATE:

As mentioned by @HansUp, adding a new column with the duplicate count probably doesn't make sense, but that really depends on what the OP originally thought of using it for. I'm leaving the answer in case it is of help for someone else.

Comment: @HansUp: The OP mentioned "Here I want a third column "Duplicate_Count"". I don't know why he may want the column, I'm just answering his question.